# Count the number of times a same value appears in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to know if there is a native javascript code that does the same thing as this:

```
function f(array,value){
    var n = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] == value){n++}
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: In my honest opinion the for loop you have is a lot cleaner than using `reduce`. There's no single built-in method to do it, the closest you can get is built-in methods that'll loop the array for you.

Comment: The function and the loop you provided does what you want it to do.  What is the reason you are looking for another method? Is it for performance reasons? Do you have a large array and want to avoid going through the whole array? Knowing what your problem is helps with the answer.

Comment: @SaeedD., for counting, you need to inspect every element.

Comment: @Nina, You can also use indexOf to find and count elements. See my working code below.  But I like RomanPerekhrest answer and use of filter.

Comment: @SaeedD., yes, but it has two loops, one while and one indexof loop.

Comment: @SaeedD: Javascript is a multi paradigm language. The OP used an imperative loop and as you know there's an opposite style called functional programming, which is based on the declarative style. So it's a legitimate question, what alternatives do exist.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

There might be different approaches for such purpose.
 And your approach with `for` loop is obviously not misplaced(except that it looks redundantly by amount of code).
Here are some additional approaches to get the occurrence of a certain value in array:

- Using `Array.forEach` method:

  ```
    var arr = [2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1];

    function getOccurrence(array, value) {
        var count = 0;
        array.forEach((v) => (v === value && count++));
        return count;
    }

    console.log(getOccurrence(arr, 1));  // 2
    console.log(getOccurrence(arr, 3));  // 3
  ```
- Using `Array.filter` method:

  ```
    function getOccurrence(array, value) {
        return array.filter((v) => (v === value)).length;
    }

    console.log(getOccurrence(arr, 1));  // 2
    console.log(getOccurrence(arr, 3));  // 3
  ```

Answer (score 45):

Another option is:

```
count = myArray.filter(x => x == searchValue).length;
```

Comment: I like the simplicity. I suggest using a `===` comparator though.

Comment: It does not work because filter returns an array with just one of the similar elements. So, the length is always one.

Answer (score 31):

You could use reduce to get there:

[Working example](https://jsbin.com/mebiwa/1/edit?js,console)

```
var a = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4];

var map = a.reduce(function(obj, b) {
  obj[b] = ++obj[b] || 1;
  return obj;
}, {});
```

Comment: My vote goes to this one since I guess this is exactly the fundamental answer to all questions starting with "give me a solution to find the number of times each... bla bla.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer here. concise and gives you a data structure which can be manipulated easier.

Answer (score 9):

Here is my solution **without using an additional object** and using `reduce`:

```
const occurrencesOf = (number,numbers) => numbers.reduce((counter, currentNumber)=> (number === currentNumber ? counter+1 : counter),0);
occurrencesOf(1, [1,2,3,4,5,1,1]) // returns 3
occurrencesOf(6, [1,2,3,4,5,1,1]) // returns 0
occurrencesOf(5, [1,2,3,4,5,1,1]) // returns 1
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use forEach

```js
let countObj = {};
let arr = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4];

let countFunc = keys => {
  countObj[keys] = ++countObj[keys] || 1;
}

arr.forEach(countFunc);

// {1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Array filter method and find the length of the new array like this

```
const count = (arr, value) => arr.filter(val => val === value).length
```

Comment: Can you make the difference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59573631/7733418 more obvious? I do not get it and you want to avoid the unfavorable impression that might cause.

Answer (score 2):

```
const arr = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"];
let count = 0;

function countValues(array, countItem) {
  array.forEach(itm => {
    if (itm == countItem) count++;
  });
  console.log(`${countItem} ${count}`);
}
countValues(arr, "c");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let ar = [2,2,3,1,4,9,5,2,1,3,4,4,8,5];

const countSameNumber = (ar: any, findNumber: any) => {
    let count = 0;
    ar.map((value: any) => {
        if(value === findNumber) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    })
    return count;
}


let set = new Set(ar);
for (let entry of set) {
    console.log(entry+":", countSameNumber(ar, entry));
}
```

Comment: Hi Rai. Thanks for your answer. Usually answers with an explanation are more welcomed there. Would you like to add an explanation to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did mine using just a for loop. It's not as sophisticated as some of the answers above but it worked for me.

```
function getNumOfTimes(arrayOfNums){
    let found = {}
        for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfNums.length; i++) {
            let keys = arrayOfNums[i].toString()
            found[keys] = ++found[arrayOfNums[i]] || 1
        }

    return found
}

getNumOfTimes([1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3])

// { '1': 1, '3': 3, '4': 3, '5': 1 }
```

Comment: I assume `units` should be `arrayOfNums`.

Comment: @DonaldDuck, yes you're right, thanks for spotting. Have fixed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `indexOf()` function to find and count each `value` in `array`

```
function g(array,value){
  var n = -1;
  var i = -1;
  do {
    n++;
    i = array.indexOf(value, i+1);
  } while (i >= 0  );

  return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let countValue = 0;

Array.forEach((word) => {
  if (word === searchValue) {
    return countValue ++;
  }
});
console.log(`The number of word 'asdf': ${countValue}`);
```

I used this code to count the number of a given word in a text which was previously converted into an array.

Answer (score -1):

```
var obj = [];
var array = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd'];

array.forEach(element => {
  let count = 1;
  array.forEach(loopo => {
    if(element == loopo)
     {
       obj[loopo] = count++;
     }
  })
});
console.log(obj);
```