# How to do projection in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to populate `orders` which is an array of type `Order`. The expected result is `orders=[{id:1,qt:4},{id:2, qt:2},{id:3,qt:2}]`. How to do so in TypeScript? I am new to it.

```
export class Product {
  constructor(public id: number, public name: string, public price: number) {}
}
export interface Order {
  id: number;
  qt: number;
}

export const products: Product[] = [
  new Product(1, 'Apple', 2.1),
  new Product(2, 'Banana', 2.2),
  new Product(3, 'Chocolate', 2.3),
  new Product(4, 'Dessert', 2.4),
];

export const cart: Product[] = [
  products[0],
  products[0],
  products[2],
  products[1],
  products[2],
  products[0],
  products[1],
  products[0],
];

export const orders: Order[] = [];
```

## Edit

For those who want to know how
`orders=[{id:1,qt:4},{id:2, qt:2},{id:3,qt:2}]` is obtained.

In the `cart`:

- the quantity of apples (`id:1`) is `qt:4`
- the quantity of bananas (`id:2`) is `qt:2`
- the quantity of chocolates (`id:3`) is `qt:2`

So by using cart, I have to obtain `orders=[{id:1,qt:4},{id:2, qt:2},{id:3,qt:2}]`. It should be clear.

Comment: `id` is a field on product, sure. But how is `qt` determined? There's no `qt` field on the `Product` class you've shown.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: `qt` represents the frequency of a certain product id in the cart.

Comment: Are you looking for something more clever than a `for` loop? Because my first instinct is the simple approach.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: Yes. Smarter like LINQ in c#.

Comment: In that case, you may find yourself disappointed. There are surely libraries out there that will LINQ-type queries, but Typescript on its own isn't going to help you too much in that department.

Comment: So how the cart is represented currently. It is not clear from where `qt` should be taken from. What data structure should be transformed to `Order[]`?

Comment: @AlekseyL. OP commented "`qt` represents the frequency of a certain product id in the cart". So it's supposed to be counted from the `cart`. The question ought to include that comment though.

Comment: The cart is represented by object like `{ 1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 2}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're looking for a "LINQ-like" solution, you probably want to use the higher order functions like `map`/`filter`/`reduce`.

Strictly, your problem cannot be solved purely with LINQ projections. Those merely represent `map` (`Select`), `concatMap`/`flatMap` (`SelectMany`), and `zip` (`Zip`). Your problem involves counting the occurences of each `id` throughout the entire array.

Pretty much every data manipulation problem can be solved with higher order folds, i.e [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in javascript land, [`Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-5.0) in C# land. This one is no exception. The first thing to do, is to *count* the occurrences of each `id`, and [build a counter object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365537/10305477).

```
cart.reduce((acc, { id }) => {
    acc[id] = (acc[id] ?? 0) + 1;
    return acc;
}, {} as Record<number, number>);
```

Essentially, you start the fold operation with an empty object, then add each `id` and its occurrence count. Every time an `id` is encountered in the `cart` array, you increment its count in the object. If the `id` doesn't already exist in the accumulating object, nullish coalescing (`acc[id] ?? 0`) uses `0` and increments that instead.

This will give you-

```
{ '1': 4, '2': 2, '3': 2 }
```

Now, you need to turn this into-

```
[ { id: 1, qt: 4 }, { id: 2, qt: 2 }, { id: 3, qt: 2 } ]
```

For that, use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) on the fold result to get-

```
> Object.entries({ '1': 4, '2': 2, '3': 2 })
[ [ '1', 4 ], [ '2', 2 ], [ '3', 2 ] ]
```

Finally, a simple [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is all you need-

```
Object.entries(...).map(([id, qt]) => ({ id: Number(id), qt }))
```

Combining all that, you have-

```
export const orders: Order[] = Object.entries(
    cart.reduce((acc, { id }) => {
        acc[id] = (acc[id] ?? 0) + 1;
        return acc;
    }, {} as Record<number, number>)
).map(([id, qt]) => ({ id: Number(id), qt }));
```

One thing to note here is that `Object.entries` is pretty inefficient since it builds up an array instead of an iterator. If you're into efficiency, roll an iterator version of `Object.entries` and use that instead, using [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)-

```
function* objEntries<T>(x: Record<string, T>): IterableIterator<[string, T]> {
  for (const k in x) {
    yield [k, x[k]];
  }
}
```